# What does this JavaScript regular expression represent?

Tags: javascript, regex

One of our legacy JavaScript code contains this line of code:

```
code.match(/if\\s*\\(/g).length
```

What does this `/if\\s*\\(/g` regex mean?

Comment: this will show you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means match "if" followed by whitespace "zero or more" times and an open parentheses. Except it should error because of the double escapes, the regular expression would be:

```
code.match(/if\s*\(/g).length
```

A regular expression literal does not use double escapes, they're used in [**RegExp Objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
var re = new RegExp('if\\s*\\(', 'g')
code.match(re).length;
```

In other words:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It all makes sense now. Not sure why it has double escapes. Thank you.

Comment: Double escapes can be valid. It just changes the meaning to: `i` followed by `f` followed by `\ ` followed by zero or more `s` then `\(`

Answer (score 0):

The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

Search a string for "ain":

```
  var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
  var res = str.match(/ain/g);
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

```
  ain,ain,ain
```

See more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp